# How to pass a component as props to another component in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component like this

```
<ReactSuperSelect placeholder="Nothing Selected" 
                        clearSearchOnSelection={true}
                        deselectOnSelectedOptionClick={true}
                        dataSource={testData}
                        multiple={true}
                        onChange={this.handlerExample} 
                        keepOpenOnSelection={true}
                        searchable={true} />
```

I assign this to a variable and passed as a props but it display there like a string.
How to achieve this?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah. I am asking about how to pass as props..

Comment: Could you show your exact setup? How are you passing it in as props and how are you rendering it?

Comment: could you provide more code, pls? Show how you assign it and pass it to another component and the contents of the target component can help greatly with figuring out the problem.

Comment: The code here is totally unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the component as below

```
const myComponent = <ReactSuperSelect placeholder="Nothing Selected" 
                    clearSearchOnSelection={true}
                    deselectOnSelectedOptionClick={true}
                    dataSource={testData}
                    multiple={true}
                    onChange={this.handlerExample} 
                    keepOpenOnSelection={true}
                    searchable={true} />
```

Next pass it as a prop to your childComponent as below.

```
<ChildComponent subComponent={myComponent}/>
```

Assuming the variable name of prop is `subComponent` (as shown above) you can show the component passed via props in the render method  of `ChildComponent` as below.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.props.subComponent}
        </div>
    )
}
```